# Remove filenames with 'not allowed' extensions in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have a PHP array of file names like `$f = [ 'file1.jpg', file2.png', 'file3.bmp', 'file4.zip', 'file5.txt'... ];`

Now how do I remove all the files from the array with not allowed extension, in this case remove everything except .jpg and .png ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code, you can add mode allowed extensions in `$allowed` array, but without dot

```
$f = array('file1.jpg', 'file2.png', 'file3.bmp', 'file4.zip', 'file5.txt' );
$allowed = array('jpg','png');

echo "<pre>before removing";
print_r($f);
echo "</pre>";

    foreach($f as $k=>$v){
        $ext = end(explode(".",$v));
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed)){
            unset($f[$k]);
        }
    }

echo "<pre>after removing";
print_r($f);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I am getting PHP Runtime Notice : Only variables should be passed by reference, at the line : $ext = end(explode(".",$v));

Comment: with above 2 arrays I am getting any notice or error, you may have some other issue.

Comment: `http://codepad.org/2idYbBvA`